# Is it possible to get the current html5 video timeframe with milliseconds?

Tags: html, video, time, milliseconds

I am trying to build a live video captioning editor and require that the JS/DOM returns the current video timeframe with milliseconds. According to the DOM, video.currentTime only returns the value in seconds. Is there anyway to get the value in/with milliseconds?

Answer (score 9):

`ontimeupdate` event gives your currentTime in seconds with milliseconds fraction represented as float number, so if you want milliseconds precision you should multiply by 1000. Here are some ways to approach it:

1. With low granularity `timeupdate` event tracking

```js
window.onTimeUpdate = (e) => {
  console.log(Math.round(e.target.currentTime * 1000));
};
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video701/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_30mb.mp4" width='320' height='240' ontimeupdate="onTimeUpdate(event)" controls='controls' autoplay></video>
```

2. But delay between `timeupdate` event is pretty big starting from 200ms, so if you want more frequent update control you can try `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` solutions, something like this:

```js
var reqId;

var startTracking = function() {
  console.log(Math.round(video.currentTime * 1000));
  reqId = requestAnimationFrame(function play() {
    console.log(Math.round(video.currentTime * 1000));
    reqId = requestAnimationFrame(play);
  });
};

var stopTracking = function () {
  if (reqId) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(reqId);
  }
};

video.addEventListener('play', startTracking);

video.addEventListener('pause', stopTracking);
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video701/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_30mb.mp4" width='320' height='240' controls='controls' autoplay></video>
```

Answer (score 7):

currentTime includes milliseconds.
Open a YouTube video, open your console, then enter
`document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].currentTime;`

You'll see the time milliseconds and beyond:
`24.530629`