# Creating an audio step / beat viewer with audio currentTime milliseconds Jquery

Tags: jquery, audio

I am working on a step sequencer / viewer that plays back a 120bpm beat (2 beats per second) and when it hits the fractions of a second it should light up the div / box accordingly. It is not working like intended... I read that currentTime should support milliseconds but something is not right. [Is it possible to get the current html5 video timeframe with milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445812/is-it-possible-to-get-the-current-html5-video-timeframe-with-millisecondsIt) just instantly lights up all the pads red as soon as it plays and doesn't remove the red when it is not on that step / beat.

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="pad p1"></div>
    <div class="pad p2"></div>    
    <div class="pad p3"></div>    
    <div class="pad p4"></div>    
    <div class="pad p5"></div>    
    <div class="pad p6"></div>    
    <div class="pad p7"></div>    
    <div class="pad p8"></div>    
</div>

<audio id="beat" controls loop autoplay>
<source src="beattest.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>


   <script>
    if (beat.currentTime < 0.25) {

            $(".p1").css("background-color", "red");
            $(".pad").not(".p1").css("background-color", "#0c2216");
    }
    if (beat.currentTime < 0.5) {

            $(".p2").css("background-color", "red");
            $(".pad").not(".p2").css("background-color", "#0c2216");
    }
    if (beat.currentTime < 0.75) {

            $(".p3").css("background-color", "red");
            $(".pad").not(".p3").css("background-color", "#0c2216");
    }
    if (beat.currentTime < 1) {

            $(".p4").css("background-color", "red");
            $(".pad").not(".p4").css("background-color", "#0c2216");
    }
   </script>
```

I also tried with no luck so far:

```
        var audio = document.getElementById('beat');
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){
    window.currentTimeMs = audio.currentTime*1000;
    console.log(currentTimeMs);
    if (beat.currentTimeMs < 250) {

        $(".p1").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".pad").not(".p1").css("background-color", "#0c2216");
    console.log('1');
}
if (beat.currentTimeMs < 500) {

        $(".p2").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".pad").not(".p2").css("background-color", "#0c2216");
}

},false);
```

Comment: `if( something = 0.5 )` sets `something` to `0.5`  and evaluates to a *truthy* value for the `if`. If you want to check that a variable holds a value, then use either `==` or  `===`. But your MediaElement.currentTime is not gonna be exactly `0.5` anyway. You'd be best holding your state in variables you do control and just set the `currentTime` or to check for a range. Also, you'll need to do so in a kind of event, either the MediaElement's `timeupdate`, either at before screen's refresh using `requestAnimationFrame`. (since your are doing something visual, better use the second).

Comment: Hey Kaiido, Thanks for the reply, I think you are right, I thought that would be the case, and tried it and also I tried less than (<) I think less than would be better since I notice it doesn't ever really hit that exact. Still not working but I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out and it works now... need to do a < && > (I noticed currentTime is never at a perfect / consistent range as well, it fluctuates):

```
var audio = document.getElementById('beat');
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate',function(){
    window.currentTimeMs = audio.currentTime*1000;

if (currentTimeMs < 250) {  
    $(".p1").css("background-color", "red");
    $(".pad").not(".p1").css("background-color", "#0c2216");     

}
if (currentTimeMs < 500 && currentTimeMs > 250) {
        $(".p2").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".pad").not(".p2").css("background-color", "#0c2216"); 

}
if (currentTimeMs < 750 && currentTimeMs > 500) {
        $(".p3").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".pad").not(".p3").css("background-color", "#0c2216");     

}
if (currentTimeMs < 1000 && currentTimeMs > 750) {
        $(".p4").css("background-color", "red");
        $(".pad").not(".p4").css("background-color", "#0c2216"); 

}
```